# v3 only show distance and not the map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

how can i make so that my google map only shows the duration and distance between these two points and not the map and the navpoints on.

is it also possible to use these outputs further on to calculate a price based on distance?
ie. 10km distance x16 per km equals 160.-?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        Henteadresse:
        <input type="text" id="txtSource" value="" style="width: 200px" />
        &nbsp; Leveringsadresse:
        <input type="text" id="txtDestination" value="" style="width: 200px" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Finn kjørerute" onclick="GetRoute()" />
        <hr />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div id="dvDistance">
        </div>
    <td>
        <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
        </div>
    </td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>

    <td>
        <div id="dvPanel" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var source, destination;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
    new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
    new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
});

function GetRoute() {
    var mumbai = new google.maps.LatLng(18.9750, 72.8258);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: mumbai
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));

  //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
    source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
    destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

    var request = {
        origin: source,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });

    //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [source],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
            var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
            var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
            var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
           dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
            dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
            dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;

        } else {
            alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to show a map, but not display the directions route on it?  Have you looked at the [DistanceMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)?

Comment: If you want to use the resulting values in calculations later, you probably want the `.value`, not the `.text` out of each of the results.  Where is it that you want to do that calculation?  Probably should be in the callback function when the data is available..

Comment: **how can i make so that my google map [...] shows [...] not the map** ...this really needs some clarification

Comment: @geocodezip  - i only want to to show the destination and duration in text form, and no map.

when it comes to the values and calculation i want this to be calculated on the same page. for example you select one radio/dropdown option that states "shipping cost", so when you push get route, it gets the variable (16.-) per km and adds it to a text string beneath duration and distance that is distance x "shipping cost" =160.- but that i can try to work out on my own, first i need the thing to just show the duration and distance, and not the map.

Comment: Radio/dropdown? There is none in your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you only need the distance and duration, not the route on the map, you can use the [DirectionsMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)
2. To use the returned data in calculations, use it inside the callback function.

   ```
   var distance = results[j].distance.text;
   var duration = results[j].duration.text;
   var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
   dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
   dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
   // 16 dollars / km
   dvDistance.innerHTML += "Cost: $" + (results[j].distance.value/1000 * 16).toFixed(2) + "<br />"; 
   dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration: " + duration;
   ```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/712zttsx/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var source, destination;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
  new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    'draggable': true
  });
});

function calculateDistances() {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
  destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [source],
    destinations: [destination],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, callback);
}

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('dvDistance');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

        var distance = results[j].distance.text;
        var duration = results[j].duration.text;
        var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
        dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
        dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
        // 16 dollars / km
        dvDistance.innerHTML += "Cost: $" + (results[j].distance.value / 1000 * 16).toFixed(2) + "<br />";
        dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration: " + duration;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      Henteadresse:
      <input type="text" id="txtSource" value="" style="width: 200px" />&nbsp; Leveringsadresse:
      <input type="text" id="txtDestination" value="" style="width: 200px" />
      <br />
      <input type="button" value="Finn kjørerute" onclick="calculateDistances()" />
      <hr />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div id="dvDistance">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="dvPanel" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```